# Sphinx - Sort results in a specific order

Tags: php, sphinx

In `Sphinx`, I want to search for rows containing some keywords and sort them in a specific order.

For example, search for words like 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Lion' and sort in an order such that rows with 'Dog' will be listed first, followed by rows with 'Cat', and then with 'Lion'.

In `Sphinx`, searching will be easy with below query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_index WHERE MATCH('test_string "DOG" | "CAT" | "Lion"')
```

How can we sort the rows in a predefined order in `Sphinx`?

Answer (score 2):

You can order with predefined list in `SQL`.

Complete SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   test_index 
WHERE  MATCH('test_string "DOG" | "CAT" | "Lion"') 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN field = 'DOG' THEN 0 
            WHEN field = 'CAT' THEN 1 
            WHEN field = 'Lion' THEN 2 
          end
```

---

Yes Sphinx doesn't support `ORDER BY CASE`. If you want to short in predefined order you can use `SPH_SORT_EXTENDED`. Example in `PHP` is following:

```
$sph->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "DOG, CAT, Lion");
```

Example:

```
Article.search "term", :sort_mode => :extended,
  :order => "Project ASC, Company ASC"
```

[**Source in detail**](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#sorting)

Comment: Sorry, I want sorting to be in Sphinx not in MySQL. Also its a full text search.

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can do something like

```
WHERE MATCH('test_string DOG | DOG | DOG | CAT | CAT | Lion')
```

Which means certain words will match multiple times. MIgh need to combine with a different ranking moder eg `OPTION ranker=wordcount`

---

Boost operator might also do something similar...

```
WHERE MATCH('test_string DOG^3 | CAT^2 | Lion')
```

(removed the quotes for brevity)

Comment: Thanks Barry! Boost operator is supported in version 2.2.3 +. I am using Sphinx 2.0.5. So, can't use boost operator at present. Tried first solution but it didn't work. I will be querying on multiple words too like 'Loyal Dog', 'Cute Cat', 'King of the Jungle is Lion'. Will need sorting to work for these too in same order.

Comment: Just use the Phrase marks to keep it in phrases ` "Loyal Dog" | "Loyal Dog" | "Cute Cat"` etc. Dont forget to use different rankers, the default ranker doesnt take much notice of the word being mutliple times.

Comment: Will try the solution and update here. Thanks once again!

Comment: Tried with different rankers. The `wordcount` ranker is close but not 100% accurate. The less relevant results comes up in some cases. Will have to go for option 2 with boost operators. Is sphinx 2.2.3 beta version stable and can be used in production?

Comment: Well there is a custom expression ranker. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#expression-ranker You dont have to just use provided ones. Can create one that incorporates the important bit from wordcount (ie `hit_count`), with some more advanced ranking, eg `lcs`. Not tested, but something like `sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25+sum(hit_count*user_weight)`